# neo4j-driver session not executing

Tags: javascript, node.js, neo4j

I am finding neo4j3.0 bolt neo4j-driver syntax very challenging. my session code just won't execute, apparently it get skipped. I have created a little test code using the example from the developers manual and surprise surprise it did the same thing. I used node-inspector to look at the code and sure enough it just skipped the "session" block. obviously I am doing something wrong...can someone tell me what it is??...the code is below:.....the code printed only the first console.log then quit.

```
var neo4j = require('neo4j-driver').v1;

var driver = neo4j.driver("bolt://localhost", neo4j.auth.basic("neo4j", "allin4k"));
var session = driver.session();
console.log("start session");
session
  .run( "CREATE (a:Person {name:'Arthur', title:'King'})" )
  .then( function()
  {
    console.log("return from second session")
    return session.run( "MATCH (a:Person) WHERE a.name = 'Arthur' RETURN a.name AS name, a.title AS title" )

  })

  .then( function( result ) {
    console.log( result.records[0].get("title") + " " + result.records[0].get("name") );
    session.close();
    driver.close();
  })
```

Answer (score 2):

Not really sure what you're expecting.

With the results of the session you run a second statement on the same session while at the same time you close it?

Your second `then` should be at the second call:

```
var neo4j = require('neo4j-driver').v1;

var driver = neo4j.driver("bolt://localhost", neo4j.auth.basic("neo4j", "allin4k"));
var session = driver.session();
console.log("start session");
session
  .run( "CREATE (a:Person {name:'Arthur', title:'King'})" )
  .then( function()
  {
    console.log("return from second session")
    session.run( "MATCH (a:Person) WHERE a.name = 'Arthur' RETURN a.name AS name, a.title AS title" ).then( function( result ) {
      console.log( result.records[0].get("title") + " " + result.records[0].get("name") );
      session.close();
      driver.close();
    })

  })
```

Comment: ...As I indicated this code sample came from the neo4j3.0 developers manual. My further research is pointing to a problem with the nested session (the second one), which could be related to a more recent question here "Neo4j BOLT query does not always work consistently".

Comment: What appers to be happening is a delay in the creation of the node while the code continues to execute. The code always complete except for the second session and when I check the database the node is created. If I had a browser connection open the nodes would not appear until after I disconnect and reconnect.....could this also due to nodejs....can you shed anymore light on this behavior ....thanks